# How to read private key buffer from windows certificate store using nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, x509certificate, mqtt, private-key

I am new to Javascript and I have the following code where I need to pass the private key buffer and ceritificate buffer data.

```
    var mqttOptions = {
            clientId: '100',
            key: fs.readFileSync('C:/Users/wssClientTest/client.key'),
            cert: fs.readFileSync('C:/Users/wssClientTest/client.crt'),
            ca: fs.readFileSync('C:/Users/wssClientTest/ca.crt'),
            secureProtocol: 'TLSv1_method',
            rejectUnauthorized: false,
            protocolId: 'MQIsdp',
            protocolVersion: 3,
            passphrase: 'edgenode',
            keepAlive: 10000,
            clean: false,
            reconnectPeriod: '1000',
            will: willMessage
        };
```

Here I am passing the key and certificate buffer data from files. I want to append the private key into the certificate and install the certificate in windows certificate store. If I do that, how can I read the certificate from the windows certificate store and get the private key from it? Please assist with some example.

Answer (score 0):

You don't EVER read the private key back from a keystore, this would defeat the point of putting it in the keystore to start with. You pass in the data you want encrypting/signing to the keystore and it gives you back the encrypted/signed data.

As I mentioned in the comments to your earlier question, use the Paho web client and just pass a "wss://" url and let the browser deal with the keys/certs from the keystore

Comment: in paho's javascript page https://www.eclipse.org/paho/clients/js/  there isn't anything provided on how to establish  wss connection getting the certificates from the browser store :( Do you have any examlple mate?

Comment: You don't explicitly get the certs from the store, the browser will do it all for you. If there are multiple certs in the store that match the TLS handshake then the browser will ask you to pick one

Comment: that means this will not work for self-signed certificates will it? it should be a certificate signed by a CA containing a chain noh?

Comment: You can add your own CA certs to the windows certificate store if needed. But self signed certs are a bad idea and should be avoided at all costs anyway

Comment: so I have to install the client certificate and the CA cert to the windows cert store and the browser will check for the right one and verify it. I'll have require certificate set to true at my mosquitto broker config. And connection would be wss://localhost:8883. Thats the summary right? Since i'm new to js and security this is so confusing